# Error message: "Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" error depsite having equal vector lengths

Tags: r, function, dataframe, replace

I am working on solving ODEs, and I need to calculate the error of a numeric solution by subtracting it from the exact solution $x(t) = e^{0.2t}x(0)$.

I have already calculated the solution for one time step, but I cannot get past the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" in my code for calculating the error. I've included my code for both solving the ODE and calculating the error.

```
#Calculating numeric solution ($$ \frac{dx}{dt} =  0.2 x $$)
fefunction<-function(x){
  ans<-0.2*x
  return(ans)
}
Tmax<-1 #length of time
dt<-0.1 #time step
numsteps<-Tmax/dt #number of steps
y<-rep(0,numsteps+1) #pre-allocating y
time<-seq(0,Tmax,dt) #setting up time vector
y[1]<-5 #initial value for the numeric solution
for(i in 1:numsteps){
  #forward Euler
  y[i+1]<-y[i]+dt*fefunction(y[i])
}
print(y[2]) #Numeric solution: 5.1

#calculating exact solution: $x(t) = e^{0.2t}x(0)$
exact<-function(t,x){ 
  ans<-exp(0.2*t)*x
  return(ans)
}
Tmax<-1 #length of time
dt<-0.1 #time step
t<-seq(0,Tmax,dt) #setting up time vector
numsteps<-Tmax/dt #number of steps
sol1<-rep(0,numsteps+1) #pre-allocating the solution
sol1[1]<-5 #initial value for the exact solution
for(i in 1:numsteps){
  #exact solution
  sol1[i+1]<-exact(t,sol1[i])
}
error<-sol1[1]-y[2]
print(error)
```

The error should be 0.0010067, as the exact solution is 5.1010067 while the numeric solution is 5.1. However, I keep receiving the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" for my calculation of the error despite having vectors of equal length.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a vector of results to a single value place in

```
sol1[i+1]<-exact(t,sol1[i])
```

to show this, individually for i = 1;

```
 i = 1
> sol1[i + 1]
[1] 0
> exact(t, sol1[i])
 [1] 5.000000 5.101007 5.204054 5.309183 5.416435 5.525855 5.637484 5.751369 5.867554 5.986087 6.107014
```

this is because `t = c(0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0)`

hence assigning exact(t, sol1[i]) to sol1[i + 1] gives this warning because your replacement has `length` 10 whilst the replacement length is just 1.